Masking a raster with only one value and defining the nodata pixels to 0 only inside the geometry
I want to calculate the coverage area of a raster inside each district of a shapefile. The raster only takes a value of 1 for the covered areas. My Python function below iterates over each row (district) of the shapefile and attempts to calculate the area covered, but it is wrong because districts that visually appear totally covered by the raster have a mean coverage less than 1. I think this is because the mask() function uses a minimum bounding box and the values outside the geometry (which I want to ignore) are replaced to 0 and included in my calculation. I just want to replace the nodata values inside the geometry to 0 so I can calculate the coverage area as a mean. How can I correct this?
def calculate_mean_coverage(raster_path, shp):

# Initialize a list to hold the mean values and district information
data = []

# Load raster
with rasterio.open(raster_path) as src:
    # Read the first band
    raster_data = src.read(1)
    no_data = src.nodata
    # Check if the raster is "empty" i.e., all values are the NoData value
    if np.all(raster_data == src.nodata):
        print("Raster is empty")
    else:
        for _, row in shp.iterrows():
            # Mask the raster with the current row's geometry
            out_image, out_transform = mask(src, [row['geometry']], crop=True)
            # Calculate the mean, missing values are used as 0's
            out_image = out_image.astype(float)
            
            # Replace no_data values with NaN and then to 0's
            if no_data is not None:
                out_image[out_image == no_data] = np.nan
            out_image_no_nan = np.nan_to_num(out_image, nan=0) # Replace np.nan with 0 for mean calculation
            mean_val = np.nanmean(out_image_no_nan)
            # Append district information and mean value to the list
            data.append({'state': row['shapeName_right'], 'district': row['shapeName_left'], 'mean_coverage': mean_val})

# Convert the list to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
return df

A visual inspection for one of the districts shows that I'm replacing NaNs inside and outside the geometry in the loop with 0, while I only want to do this for areas inside the geometry and leave area outside the geometry as NaN.

(I'm not a Python coder, so I used ChatGPT a lot, hence the inefficient coding.)

Debugging code generated by ChatGPT is most efficiently done with right-click-delete.

What is the nodata value of your raster, if any? You can use gdalinfo to find out. You want, for each district calculate the area covered by the raster, no matter what value the raster have?

@Bera, essentially the raster only takes a value of 1 for the areas it covers. There is no data on the uncovered areas. So yes, I want to calculate the area covered by the raster for each district. Do you know how i can do this?
